# Has adding "ee" to a name have a special meaning?

Tags: meaning

I've recently discovered a guy named Gary Vaynerchuk.
At his Youtube channel he named himself as garyvee.

Besides his last inital is V (spoken vee),
does the double ee has any meaning ?

Comment: the "vee" just means "V". Gary V. = garyvee.

Comment: It’s the phonetic spelling of the pronunciation of the first letter of his last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"vee" is way to spell out the sound of the letter V, his last initial.